# How to link DayPicker to existing input element

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

I'm using react-day-picker DayPicker (not DayPickerInput) and have an existing element I want to use to drive the date popup. I can't figure out how to pre-feed the date from the element to the calendar and highlight the given date. All the other functionality, e.g. capturing the user chosen date and populating the element are working fine. So if my input element has Nov 11, 2019, and I click on it, I want the popup to go to that date and show it as selected. The current behavior is that it shows the current month and date. I've tried to set the selectedDays={this.state.selectedDay}, but that doesn't seem to work. Note that I am new to reactjs, and this could be the gap in my understanding.

Thanks for any suggestions you may have.

Answer (score 0):

Found at least one way to achieve the behavior I was looking for. There is a DayPicker property "initialMonth" that will display the current month. Note that this only needs to be populated only with year and month:

```
initialMonth = {new Date(selectedDate.getFullYear(), selectedDate.getMonth())}
```